# why decryption fails for certain data only

Tags: java, aes

I used sample code provided on this site by user. I need to encrypt password and store in file for future use. When user try to use system, I fetch password from file, decrypt it and use it for further processing. So I can't use different key during each encryption/decryption request. So I use fixed byte[] to store key instead of calling KeyGenerator.generateKey(). Below is full code.

```
public class App 
{
    static byte[] seckey=null;
    static
    {
        try
        {
            KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
              kgen.init(128); 

                        // Generate the secret key specs.             
                        // SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
                        // seckey = skey.getEncoded();
                        // above won't work as can't generate new secret key for decrypt. Have to use same key for encrypt and decrypt

                        // seckey = new byte[]{0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f};
                        seckey = new byte[]{(byte)172,(byte)236,(byte)125,(byte)222,(byte)188,(byte)33,(byte)210,(byte)4,(byte)202,(byte)31,(byte)188,(byte)152,(byte)220,(byte)104,(byte)62,(byte)64};


        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {   

        String password = encrypt("A123456"); //working
        System.out.println(password);
        System.out.println(decrypt(password));

        String password = encrypt("A*501717"); //NOT working
        System.out.println(password);
        System.out.println(decrypt(password));

    }    
    public static String encrypt(String passwd)
    {
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(seckey, "AES");
        byte[] output;
        try
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

            // encryption pass
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            output = cipher.doFinal(passwd.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to encrypt password.");
            output = "".getBytes();
        }

        return new String(output);

    }

    public static String decrypt(String passwd)
    {
        if (!StringUtils.isNotBlank(passwd))
            return "";

            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(seckey, "AES");

        byte[] output;
        try
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            // decryption pass
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            output = cipher.doFinal(passwd.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to decrypt password");
            output = "".getBytes();
        }

        return new String(output);

    }
   }
```

The issue is, it works for most of the time but for certain character sequence it is faling to decrypt. e.g. presently not working for A123456. Then I changed secret key to below

```
seckey = new byte[]{0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f};
```

after that it worked for A123456 but then failed for A*3qwe (which worked with earlier secret key. So I am totally not able to understand why is it not working for only some data?

Could someone help me please where am I doing wrong?

Comment: I got to know below from another thread. @emboss

Do not turn your encrypted data into a String - this will and change the encrypted output. There's no guarantee that new String(byte[]).getBytes() returns the exact same byte array! So you should leave the encrypted data as what it is - a stream of bytes. Thus encrypt should return byte[] instead and decrypt should take byte[] as input - this is a working example:

But in the case I am storing encrypted password in file, what is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using Base64Encoder. Basically encrypted data can have some characters not possible to store in normal txt file and so decryption will fail.  So I used Base64Encoder to encode encrypted string. This encoded characters are normal ascii characters and can be easily stored in txt file.  Reverse thing is required to get original data i.e. first decode and then decrypt the string stored in file.